# Equivalent ggplot2 alternative to gplots's balloonplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gplots

I really like how balloonplot generates the balloon plots with the grid, moreover it keeps the cells with value of zero but does not show the circle.  Here is an example,

```
dt <- as.table(as.matrix(mtcars[1:10,]))
balloonplot(t(dt), xlab ="", ylab="", label = FALSE, show.margins = FALSE, cum.margins=F)
```

When I tried to generate this in ggplot is a mess, because I can't get the grid to show up correctly and moreover the cells with zero are showing up as dot and not blank.

```
ggplot(melt(dt), aes(x =X2, y = X1))  +geom_point( aes(size=value),shape=21, colour="black", fill="skyblue")
```

Is there a way to plot this with ggplot OR alternatively save the gplot as a ggplot object?  The reason why I'm I need a ggplot object is because I plan to sticth this as a bigger overall figure with pathwork.

```
# this fails 
as.ggplot(balloonplot(t(dt), xlab ="", ylab="", label = FALSE, show.margins = FALSE))
```

thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The closest I could get was the ggpubr balloon plot - does this suit your needs?

```
library(tidyverse)
#install.packages("ggpubr")
library(ggpubr)

mtcars[1:10,] %>%
ggballoonplot(size.range = c(-0.5,10), rotate.x.text = FALSE,
              ggtheme = theme_minimal(base_size = 14)) +
  ggtitle(label = "Balloon Plot for x by y",
          subtitle = "Area is proportional to Frequency") +
  scale_x_discrete(position='top') +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14),
        plot.title.position = "plot",
        plot.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(face = "bold"),
        axis.ticks = element_blank()) +
  geom_tile(color = "black", fill = "transparent")
```

[image: example_balloon_plot.png]

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
library(tidyverse)
dt2 <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(mtcars[1:10,]))

dt2 %>%
  rownames_to_column("Car") %>%
  gather(Variable, Value, -Car) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Variable, y = Car, size = Value)) +
  geom_point(colour = "sky blue") +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(-1, 10)) +
  labs(title = "Balloon Plot for x by y",
     subtitle = "Area is proportional to Freq.",
     x = "",
     y = "") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, I had something similar as well, where I plot it in two layers, the first setting alpha to 0 however the same issued occur which that the grid lines are crossing the circles and not surrounding the circles as with balloonplot.

Comment: @Ahdee I see what you mean. Well to make your zero cells blank instead of zero, simply make the lower end of the size scale negative, like this: scale_size_continuous(range = c(-1, 10)). That should fix one of your issues.